# PostgreSQL - additional condition over the given in WHERE clause in dependency on user's role

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles

I have a table with such columns as `a int`, `b boolean`. All users in database have privileged or non-privileged role. Privileged users have access to all rows from table, non-privileged - only to those rows where `b` is true.

So when non-privileged user executes `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query it must save it's `WHERE` condition but also filter all rows what aren't `b`.

---

Example: if we have in table:

```
a | c
--+--
1 | T
2 | T
3 | F
4 | F
```

and privileged user executes `SELECT  FROM table WHERE a > 1`, he must get

```
a | c
--+--
2 | T
3 | F
4 | F
```

whilst non-privileged user on the same query must get

```
a | c
--+--
2 | T
```

Is there any ways to implement it using triggers or something?

Comment: You can't add "and b>0" for non privileged user ?

Comment: RLS is not the option?.. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html, what's your version?

Comment: @VaoTsun looks like what I need. I'm working with databases for the first time, didn't know about that,

Comment: @VaoTsun, have you any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238936/postgresql-infinite-recursion-detected-in-policy-for-relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have version 9.5 and higher - use

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

> In addition to the SQL-standard privilege system available through
>   GRANT, tables can have row security policies that restrict, on a
>   per-user basis, which rows can be returned by normal queries or
>   inserted, updated, or deleted by data modification commands. This
>   feature is also known as Row-Level Security.

Comment: Can it be used when `USING` clause contain `SELECT` query from the same table on which this policy is set? I mean it's raising `infinite recursion detected in policy for relation`.

Comment: please show the code with error in new post. but in short - yes are ot supposed to recurse rules or triggers

Answer (score 0):

One method users a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from table t
    where c = 'F' or
          exists (select 1 from users u where u.user = current_user and u.role = 'privileged');
```

Then, access the table only through the view.